# Could not determine Java version using executable C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1\bin\java.exe

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Could not determine Java version using executable C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1\bin\java.exe.

This error appeared when I tried to create a new project in IntelliJ IDEA Version 2018.1.2 with Gradle. It said:

> sync failed: Could not determine Java version using executable C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1\bin\java.exe

==================

I fixed the problem by uninstalling jdk 10 and installing jdk8.

Comment: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/4503

Comment: reply to guleryuz: thank you, I fixed the problem by uninstalling jdk 10 and installing jdk8

Answer (score 64):

For JDK 10 you will need Gradle 4.7+ which is not used by default in IntelliJ IDEA (current version IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.4).

To fix this issue install latest Gradle for your OS ([Install guide](https://gradle.org/install/)). For MacOS you can use Homebrew:

```
brew install gradle
```

Go to your project directory:

```
cd ~/path/to/your/project/
```

Generate Gradle Wrapper script with the version you installed (in my case it is 4.8):

```
gradle wrapper --gradle-version 4.8
```

This command is going to download Gradle 4.8, create scripts gradlew and gradlew.bat for your current project. From this point, you should use these scripts in the command-line.

Next step, is to make sure that IntelliJ IDEA uses those, instead of built-in Gradle distribution and you can do this by opening IntelliJ preferences and search for "gradle" (this will be in "Build, Execution, Deployment / Build Tools / Gradle").

In this section of the settings select:

**Select “Use gradle ‘wrapper’ task configuration”**

Apply changes, press ok and re-build (re-sync) Gradle and everything should be fine. I hope this helps.

Comment: In case the gradle wrapper script is already there, the upper command won't work. Instead you have to edit `~/path/to/your/project/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` and change the value of `distributionUrl` to `https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.8-bin.zip`.

Comment: This solved my issue. I was using `idea` plugin as a workaround using IDEA but somehow the autowiring and some configurations are not properly configured. After having the wrapper in my root project > import project > user gradle wrapper > everything works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, @idleherb. Upgrading to gradle 4.8 solved my issue ;-)

Comment: For a legacy project, which must be compiled with JDK 1.8, I need to open _File_, _Project Structure..._, then under _Platform Settings_, _SDKs_, remove the _11_ item, using the **+** button. I'm using IntelliJ IDEA ULTIMATE 2018.3 under macOS Mojave 10.14.2.

Comment: This worked for me, OP did any of these answers work for you?

Answer (score 13):

Even if you're using Linux the solution remains the same.

Inside the root folder of your Project(Working Directory) >>

```
gradle/wrapper/
```

There's a file named >>

```
gradle-wrapper.properties
```

Change the distributionUrl line (Outdated Version):

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-bin.zip
```

To the following distributionUrl (Compatible/Correct Version):

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.8-bin.zip
```

Don't forget to configure IntelliJ IDEA Settings to use the Gradle-Wrapper Configurations.

Comment: This is really awesome. Just open the URL http://services.gradle.org/distributions/ and find the latest version

Answer (score 10):

Below is what i did to solve this issue on Windows 10 with IntelliJ 2018.1.5 and Java 10.0.1 JDK

1. Downloaded the new gradle version(latest is 4.8.1 at the time of this post) from: https://gradle.org/releases
2. Followed the following steps mentioned at: https://gradle.org/install/

(i) Microsoft Windows users

Create a new directory C:\Gradle with File Explorer.

Open a second File Explorer window and go to the directory where the Gradle distribution was downloaded. Double-click the ZIP archive to expose the content. Drag the content folder gradle-4.8.1 to your newly created C:\Gradle folder.

(ii) Added PATH C:\Gradle\gradle-4.8.1\bin to environment variable

3. After above went to File --> Settings-->Build Tools --> Gradle and did set Gradle home to C:/Gradle/gradle-4.8.1
4. Then went to View --> Tool Windows --> Gradle and hit the Refresh all Gradle projects icon.

Answer (score 7):

Solution summary:

- Turn back to older version of jdk
- Remove problematic `jdk`(s) from `intelliJ`

A full demonstration is given below for `intelliJ` in `ubuntu 18.04.1`

[image]

fig1: Installing `openjdk-8`.

[image]

fig2: Adding jdk8 to **Project Structure**. Click `+` button then choose `JDK`. Now choose `JDK home path` to jdk8. Mine was, as you can see from fig3, `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64`

[image]

fig3: openjdk-8 is added to `intelliJ`. [a:] Time to  remove newer versions of `jdk` from `intelliJ`.

[image]
fig4: Select `10` (notice that the `JDK home path` contains `java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64`) and press `-` button to remove `10`.

[image]
fig5: after removal of `jdk-10` select jdk-8(named `1.8` in fig5) and press `ok`.

[image]
fig6: Now go to `File`->`Settings`->**`Build, Execution, Deployment`**->`Build tools`->`Gradle`->`Gradle JVM` and choose the same path that you have set as `JDK home path` while adding `1.8` in `Project Structure` and press `Ok`. Click `Build` and choose `Make new module app` and the app module should be created. Now if pressing `Run` and choosing `app` module gets your app running, you have a good day :) and if not, recheck activities mentioned in fig3[a] & fig6 once.

Comment: At last, a decent answer! Thanks!

Comment: It's better to upgrade Gradle than to downgrade your JDK, which the other answers have pointed out.

Answer (score 6):

Going to:

```
File >> Settings >> Build, Execution, Deployment >> Build Tools >> Gradle
```

and selecting:

```
Use local gradle distribution
```

fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

It's most likely your gradle version. Gradle 4.7+ has JDK 10 support.

Answer (score 1):

After downloading my latest Gradle version and changing the path environment variable to C:\Gradle\gradle-4.10-bin\gradle-4.10\bin, not what was on the instructions, and changing to "Use local gradle distrubution" under Settings- Build, Execution, Deployment - Gradle
It worked for me.

Comment: And I also had to disable offline mode.

Answer (score 0):

i had to un-install my intelliJ along with cache and all histories, remove my project... Then i re-installed intellij and downloaded my project's fresh version again.

As a last step, i had to define new sdk for my project. Previously, it was showing 2-3 SDKs. after re-installation, there were none. i added one.
To add SDK in Intellij:
Go to- File- Project Structure- Project Settings- Project SDK...

Added one sdk here to point to the jdk installed path.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with IntelliJ version2018.1.6 x64. I installed Java8 and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

same in mac == Could not determine Java version using executable /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java.
this help me

```
cd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
```

then run

```
sudo rm -rf jdk-11.0.2.jdk
```

after that try to build

it will request SDK select it from Contents

Answer (score 0):

## USE SAME ANDROID STUDIO JAVA VERSION

## STEPS WINDOWS

1. the java version found at path

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr
```

2. we need to edit enviroment variable of "JAVA_HOME" to be equal "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr"
   you can set from cmd by open as adminstartor, then write this command:

```
setx -m JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr"
```

3. test by echo the JAVA_HOME from cmd

```
echo %JAVA_HOME%
```

4- Restart Android Studio, then call this command from termnial.

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```