# Unable to set up intellij for an android app in kotlin

Tags: android, intellij-idea, kotlin

I installed intelliJ first. Then the Java and Android SDKs.

When I click `Create New Project` I'm not sure what to do next. The options are:

- Android - create new android project - Android Studio
- Kotlin - Mobile Android/iOS

If i go with the first option it gives me an error saying: "

> sync failed. Could not determine Java version using executable C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin\java.exe."

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Which os are u using?

Comment: Windows 10 Pro on a desktop PC.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50121333/could-not-determine-java-version-using-executable-c-program-files-java-jdk-10-0

Comment: Followed your link and installed the latest version of gradle. IntelliJ gave a new error saying "sync failed, cause B0" The answer in the link tells me to run a command for the wrapper version but don't say WHERE to type in that command. I give up. Installed android studio and its working out of the box.

Comment: uninstall jdk 10 and install jdk8